# A Sequences order cannot be predicted beforehand, but is deterministic

Tags: phrase-requests

I need a single word or short phrase that describes the following behavior:

> If I, without any further information, ask for the sequence, its order will look random and cannot be predicted.
>   But if I ask a second time I will get the same order as the first time.

My current explanation is that *"the lists order is `essentially random, but will stay the same over multiple runs`"* (coming from an IT-background). This is a bit long and unwieldy and I wonder if there is a shorter version to express this.

Ideally I could say *"the lists order is `<...>`"*

Comment: *random but static [or fixed]*

Answer (score 1):

This is [pseudorandom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandomness):  something that appears random but is actually deterministic and repeatable.  *[Pseudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-)* is a prefix meaning "pretending, or appearing, to be" - as in "pseudonym" for example.

In computer programming pseudorandomness is usually achieved with a **seed**:  an input given to the start of the random number generator.  If not given a seed, the generator will create an unpredictable series of numbers, but if given a seed, it will produce a series of numbers which **looks** random, but will be the same every time (for the same seed).

Comment: With or without a seed, the random number generator is pseudorandom. The seed is only there to choose which pseudorandom sequence should be used.

Comment: @jimm101 that's a technical distinction which I think is unimportant.  The key thing is **predictability** - without a seed, even if it's pseudorandom under the hood, the user has **no way of predicting** which number will come next, and so to all intents and purposes it can be called "random".

Comment: It's not "a technical distinction", it's wrong. A sequence can be both pseudorandom, and NOT repeatable, and is so whenever a developer doesn't set a random seed. If the OP states that the sequence is pseudorandom, it's misleading people, and doesn't meet the requirements of "essentially random, but will stay the same over multiple runs". It's "essentially random", full stop.

Comment: @jimm101 *"essentially random, but will stay the same over multiple runs"* isn't a **requirement**, it's the OP's first attempt to explain what was happening, which they said they were unhappy with (as an explanation).  I'm suggesting they describe it as pseudorandom instead.

Comment: "This is a bit long and unwieldy and I wonder if there is a shorter version to express this" is the requirement I'm referring to.

Answer (score 0):

These sequences are usually called [pseudo random](https://www.google.com/search?q=pseudo%20random&rlz=1CASMAI_enUS715US715&oq=psudo%20random&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.17655j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

> A pseudorandom process is a process that appears to be random but is not. Pseudorandom sequences typically exhibit statistical randomness while being generated by an entirely deterministic causal process. Such a process is easier to produce than a genuinely random one, and has the benefit that it can be used again and again to produce exactly the same numbers, which is useful for testing and fixing software.
>   [- Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandomness)

Your original phrase is:

- the list[‘]s order is essentially random, but will stay the same over multiple runs

A list that is pseudorandom is “essentially random” in the sense that it is *statistically* random. Because the sequence is deterministic, the same values will be produced across multiple runs, where the *software* is made to repeat identically across runs.

This contrasts with unrepeatable sequences such as those based on temperature sampling.

Comment: I wish downvoters would leave a comment.  I think we both answered the question.

Comment: Downvote for being incorrect.

Comment: @jimm101  Thank you for the feedback.  the down-vote does alert me to search for a flaw in my answer.

Comment: @jimm101 Are you referring to the spelling: "pseudo random" with a space here, as opposed to Max's "pseudorandom" without a space?

Comment: @Lawrence No, it's factually incorrect. Pseudorandom refers to the fact that the numbers are genuinely random, but this does NOT mean the sequence is repeatable. That's the OP's question.

Comment: @jimm101 From a theoretical computer science perspective, I disagree. I’ve edited the answer to elaborate. Pseudorandom numbers are inherently repeatable. If they weren’t, they would be truly random.

Comment: @Lawrence In comp sci terms, it's only repeatable if you know the seed and algorithm, which is not always available in any pseudorandom sequence. For instance, if the seed is based  on a temperature sample unknown for future runs, it's still a pseudorandom sequence, but not repeatable.

Comment: @jimm101 The algorithm is certainly available - we are talking about multiple runs, not multiple programs. Changing the seed is a red herring. The point is that pseudorandom numbers are repeatable, not that one *must* call them in a repeatable fashion.

Comment: Red herring? It's a condition in the case you're referring to of the sequence being repeatable. If a device uses a pseudorandom generator  seeded by a geiger counter, you won't be able to get a repeatable sequence. It's not sufficient. Simply adding the word "repeatable" makes it sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

All software-generated "random" numbers are pseduorandom, so that's not sufficient.

What you have is a ***repeatable* random sequence**, or ***repeatable* psedorandom sequence**, to be strictly correct. That captures that you can repeat the sequences at will.

Matlab's random number documentation has for [commentary](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/random-numbers-in-matlab.html) to this effect, and for instance, in an article entitled *[Generate Random Numbers That Are Repeatable](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/generate-random-numbers-that-are-repeatable.html)*.

Answer (score -1):

You have one part of your answer already in your question: **deterministic**, other part is **chaotic**.

Your system is chaotic and deterministic, or in other words it displays property called "[deterministic chaos](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Deterministic_chaos)".